# Should I say Where Have You Been To or Where Have You Been In?

Tags: word-usage

If I want to ask someone how many places he/she has visited before. Should I say `in` or `to`?

What if I want to restrict the place in a country, like the US. How should I ask then?

For example, which is correct of these two sentences:
...
Where have you been **to** in the US?
or
Where have you been in the US?
...

Thanks

Comment: Both to and in are not necessary. You can simply say, _Where have you been_

Comment: This really needs more context. Basically "been to" refers to travel, while "been in" refers to just being/existing in some country. It could be either.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the middle of a conversation "Where have you been?" would work fine.

If you're starting up a new conversation or if you want to restrict the question to only places in the US you would need more context. In this case, "Which cities have you visited in the United States?" would be good.